# Autofocus with knockout js does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js in MVC3 application. I'm quite new to knockout so the question may seem a little bit dumb.

I want to have an input to be focused when the page loads. The things I already tried, are:

```
<input type="text" class="text-field" data-bind="attr: { autofocus: autofocus }
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="text-field" data-bind="hasFocus: true
```

but both didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Just small update. This is the whole view of the input.

```
<input type="text" class="text-field" data-bind="value: RegistrationNumber, valueUpdate: 'blur', enterKey: $root.proceedToServicestPage, hasFocus: true" />
```

I thought that the issue could be because of the order of binder calls and tried to place hasFocus:true in the different positions(from first to last binders). This didn't help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `autofocus` attribute, because this is done by the browser when the document is loaded, which is *before* your JavaScript (Knockout) has had a chance to run to set the attribute.

Your second option should work. I can repro using this View:

```html
<input type="text" value="Aaaaaaa" data-bind="hasFocus: false" /><br />
<input type="text" value="Be Selected!" data-bind="hasFocus: true" /><br />
<input type="text" value="Cccccc" data-bind="hasFocus: false" />
```

And this JS:

```
ko.applyBindings({});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brC5L/) for a demo.

Comment: I tried hasFocus: true as well and it didn't work for me. Probably this is som internal conflict in my code, will do more investigation on it

Answer (score 1):

Coming very late to the party, but maybe it will help someone. As @jeroen says, the attribute has to be set within the knockout binding. In fact `autofocus` can be set there - it's just a question of correct syntax. I was able to solve it with either of the following:

`data-bind="attr: { autofocus: 'autofocus' }` which gives an attribute in the resulting markup of `autofocus="autofocus"`

`data-bind="attr: { autofocus: '' }` which gives an attribute in the resulting markup of just `autofocus`

either of these worked in Chrome for me